# Why is GetConnect/GetX/Flutter not calling my backend and returning a null object?

Tags: flutter-getx

I'm using get: 4.6.5

I have defined a provider

```
class CredentialsProvider extends GetConnect implements GetxService {
  @override
  void onInit() {
    httpClient.defaultDecoder =
        (val) => Auth.fromJson(val as Map<String, dynamic>);
    httpClient.baseUrl = 'http://localhost:1337/api/';
    super.onInit();
  }
  Future<Response<dynamic>> postCredentials(Credentials credentials) async {
    return await post('auth/local', credentials);
  }
}
```

In my binding class add it as a dependency

```
class LoginBinding extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut(() => CredentialsProvider());
    Get.lazyPut(() => LoginController());
  }
}
```

And register the LoginView as a route

```
GetPage(
  name: "/login",
  page: () => const LoginView(),
  binding: LoginBinding(),
)
```

And added it to my controller

```
class LoginController extends GetxController {
  final provider = Get.put(CredentialsProvider());
//...
}
```

The controller is used in my LoginView

```
class LoginView extends GetView<LoginController> {...}
```

In my MaterialButton of the LoginView I use the onPressed to call the provider and get the result object Auth and print it out as json.

```
onPressed: () {
  var c = Credentials(
      identifier: controller.emailController.text,
      password: controller.passwordController.text);
 controller.provider.postCredentials(c).then((value) {
    var auth = value.body as Auth;
    print(auth.toJson());
  });
},
```

I generated my Auth model from JSON using the GetX cli:

```
class Auth {
  String? jwt;
  User? user;

  Auth({this.jwt, this.user});

  Auth.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    jwt = json['jwt'];
    user = json['user'] != null ? User?.fromJson(json['user']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['jwt'] = jwt;
    if (user != null) {
      data['user'] = user?.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class User {
  int? id;
  String? username;
  String? email;
  String? provider;
  bool? confirmed;
  bool? blocked;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;

  User(
      {this.id,
      this.username,
      this.email,
      this.provider,
      this.confirmed,
      this.blocked,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt});

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    username = json['username'];
    email = json['email'];
    provider = json['provider'];
    confirmed = json['confirmed'];
    blocked = json['blocked'];
    createdAt = json['createdAt'];
    updatedAt = json['updatedAt'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id'] = id;
    data['username'] = username;
    data['email'] = email;
    data['provider'] = provider;
    data['confirmed'] = confirmed;
    data['blocked'] = blocked;
    data['createdAt'] = createdAt;
    data['updatedAt'] = updatedAt;
    return data;
  }
}
```

What I get in the console is

```
flutter: {jwt: null}
```

And my localhost service is never called.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the decoder for the request being different that for the response. So I ended up with something like this:

```
  Future<Auth> postCredentials(Map<String, dynamic> body) async {
    var response = await post(
        contentType: 'application/json',
        decoder: (val) => Auth.fromJson(val as Map<String, dynamic>),
        "/api/auth/local",
        body);
      return response.body as Auth;
  }
```

And I call this via

```
controller.provider.postCredentials(credentials.toJson());
```